# Observe text in subclass of UITextView

Tags: swift, text, uitextview, subclass

I want to observe the var text! property of UITextView, I do not want to use a delegate.

My solution is this:

```
class MessageTextView: UITextView {

override var text: String! {
        didSet {
            print(text)
        }
    }
}
```

But it does not get called when typing in the textfield of the UITextView.
I tried textStorage and selectedRange as well. For me it only makes sense to override text, but it does not work. Any solution?

Edit:
This is my solution:

```
deinit {

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UITextView.textDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func setObserverNotification() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateText), name: UITextView.textDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @objc private func updateText() {
      // Do updates here
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For me it only makes sense to override text, but it does not work.

It seems unlikely that a UITextView actually sets any of the properties that you tried to override every time you type a character. The actual content of a text view is kept in a UITextStorage object, and that's created once and modified as necessary, so an override of the `textStorage` setter is going to be called once at best, not every time you type. The `text` setter won't get called at all due to edits -- you can call it to get or set the contents, but edits don't change the entire content.

If you want to find out when a text view is notified but don't want to use a delegate, than you can listen for notifications instead. `UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification` gets sent whenever there's a change to the text.